# When an Erdos-Renyi graph is locally tree like?

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs, erdos

I would like to know when an ER graph is locally treeing like. [In this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55727/sparse-graphs-are-locally-tree-like).
I found this comment:

> I think $N$ is $\log2|V|$, or something like that, in that paper.
>   They consider binary vectors of length $N$. Furthermore, "most" sparse
>   graphs have logarithmic diameter (say, random regular graphs of
>   constant degree $d\geq3$, or the giant component of Erdos-Rényi random
>   graphs with $p=\frac{c}{n}$ and $c>1$ a constant), rather than linear.

Where can I found this result about ER graphs?

Comment: Did you look into *any* book on random graphs?

Comment: @BorisBukh I'm reading: van der Hofstad. Random Graphs and Complex Networks, 2016. http://www.win.tue.nl/~rhofstad/NotesRGCN.html.
 And I haven't found it.

Comment: I was not familiar with the book, and I concede the point: that book does analyze the giant component in a way from which it is impossible to extract the bound on the diameter.  (Since it analyzes the complement of the giant component). Have a look at Theorem 10.19 in Bollobas's book on random graphs. It should also be contained in Janson-Luczak-Rucinski, but I do not have it handy.

Answer (score 1):

it has to do with the clustering coefficient.

See the bottom of page 5 here:

https://aaronclauset.github.io/courses/3352/csci3352_2021_L3.pdf